# Eclipse not telling me line of error origin?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I seem to recall that eclipse used to give you the line number of an error but now I noticed when getting a

```
IO ERROR java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
```

That is all it says.  Is this a setting or what governs whether or not Eclipse can guide you to the problem code?

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it a stacktrace (does not look like one) or program output?

Comment: Looks like output from some kind of logging framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a setting, that error is being swallowed by some code that you're using, either in a library, or code you've written.

My money is on Logging as Perception noted.

Comment: Perception is a person. :)  Well, probably.  He mentioned logging in a comment on your original post.

Comment: Ah okay.  Unfamiliar project file this.

Comment: Lol, I'd just realized that.  Sorry

Comment: Post some more details of your project, libraries you're using, more of the console output might help too.

Comment: Only using flexJson.  That was the only output.  Thanks, that's probably all I needed to know.